# What would be the value of variable after executing the following statement

Tags: java

I'm lil bit confused about this question which i found while doing 1 vasic java quiz

question is: 
What would be the value of variable c after executing

```
int c = Integer.parseInt("a");
```

I think answer would be 97, which is ASCII value of "a"

am I correct?

Comment: No. Run the code and you'll see what happens.

Comment: why not just [try](http://ideone.com/XcjYjH)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple attempt to run the code would have yielded the result.

Comment: quiz has lots of question ..was looking for explanation...but giving it a try though .. :)

Comment: But you can try it for yourself, observe the result, and ask a question *if* the result is different - at which point your question can include the actual result, alongside the reasoning for your expectation. Hint: try reading the documentation for `Integer.parseInt(String)` first.

Comment: `a` is not a digit for decimal so you get a NumberFormatException.  Note: if it was Hexidecimal you were parsing it would be `10`

Comment: @JonSkeet You're not suggesting that the documentation may actually contain an explanation are you?  Aren't explanations much better if they're written on Stack Overflow by Internet strangers; than in the language documentation provided by the people who create the language?

Comment: I got NumberFormatException, I'm not sure about exceptions and exception handing, but would definitely refer documentation

Comment: @DavidWallace Totally agree with you, that is the reason i approach here first, because it is much easier to understand by experts explanation here than by "official documentation".

Comment: @JigarPatel a word of warning.  If you intend to become a professional programmer, you are going to have to learn to look up documentation. And to run programs if you want to know what happens when you run them. Your mother is not always going to be on hand to spoon-feed you your breakfast.

Comment: no minimal research is done here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a simple attempt to run the code would yield the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws a `NumberFormatException`. From the [Javadoc on Integer.parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> **Throws:**
>   NumberFormatException - if the String does not contain a parsable int.

Retrieving the ASCII value of a character is done like this:

```
char ch='a';
System.out.println((int)ch);
```

Comment: [A char value…represents…(a) code unit… of the UTF-16 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. So, since ASCII is a subset of Unicode, it would only be an ASCII value if the character was character in common.

Answer (score 1):

When you will execute the statement like-

```
int c = Integer.parseInt("a");
System.out.println("a="+a);
```

Result would be exception at line 1

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"`

for printing ASCII value you will have to just do this-

```
int c = 'a';
System.out.println("ASCII value for a: "+c);
```

Result would be-

```
ASCII value for a: 97
```

Answer (score 0):

`int a=Integer.parseInt(String object)` parses the string argument to an integer meaning whatever String is passed, its converted to an equivalent integer, say for an instance

```
int a=Integer.parseInt("123");
```

a holds the value 123 but if you pass anything but integer as strings in it, it throws and Exception